# Filtering date within daterange and show data of one template to another template in django

Tags: django, templates, model

I have created many sitting dates by using following Sitting model:

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False,unique=True)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = TreeForeignKey('Genre', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

Output of sitting template as following format:

[image]

I also designed another model named Circular:

```
class Circular(models.Model):
    cir_no = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    sit_start_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    sit_end_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    sess_no = models.ForeignKey(Session,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parl_no = models.ForeignKey(Parliament,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('cir_no', 'sess_no',)
```

Using Circular model I will create different circulars. Suppose I will create Circular no-1 for the period of 31 August to 30 September 2016. In this case When I will view circular no-1 it will only shows those sittings  that are between above mentioned dates inclusive. And this circular will also contain the above mentioned Ministry/Division table. Should I include the sitting template in the circular template?

How can I do that. Any help will be much appreciated. 
**Edit:**
Here is sitting_list.html template:

```
{% block content %}

    <table  cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
      <th>Sitting Day & Date</th>
      <th>Ministry/Division</th>

        </tr>
        {% for sitting in sittings %}
        <tr>
           <td> {{ sitting.sit_date|date:"l, d F, Y" }}</td>
            <td>

                 {% for genre in sitting.genre.get_descendants %}

                    {{ genre }},

                 {% endfor %}
                <p>(Ballot: {{ sitting.ballot_date}})</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i completely understand you right. But one way to get `sittings` for the period of a `circular` (without an explicit model relation) could look as this:

```
class Circular(models.Model):
    # ...
    sit_start_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    sit_end_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    # ...
    @property
    def sittings(self):
        qs = Sitting.objects.filter(sit_date__gte=self.sit_start_date, sit_date__lte=self.sit_end_date)
        return qs
```

Then you can use this propperty on a 'circular' instance:

```
c = Circular.objects.get(pk=1)
c.sittings
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tomorrow I will check it whether work or not

Comment: When I only used {{ c.sittings}} in new template, it gave correct sittings but not related ministry/division information. When I used {% if c.sittings %}
        {% include 'genre/sitting_list.html' %}
    {% endif %} in new template it gave all sittings and related ministry/division data without following range restrictions.

Comment: i'm not a magician... how does your `genre/sitting_list.html` template look like?

Comment: Sorry, I posted my sitting_list.html in Edit portion.

Comment: and where does the `sittings` come from? this looks like quite a mess... you obviously have to pass the corresponding queryset to your template - how else should this work? so e.g. use `{% include 'genre/sitting_list.html' with sittings=c.sittings %}`.

Comment: Yes, this work. But 'c = Circular.objects.get(pk=1)' is work for circular no-1 but when it changes to 2, 3 and so on how should I change it dynamically?

Comment: this is a completely different & unrelated question. i would suggest you to have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/